# Get currently active connection information on grails 3.3.9

Tags: grails, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

On grails 2 it provides a bean called dataSourceUnproxied, that lets the application fetch the information on currently active no. of connection in the pooled datasource with

```
ctx.getBean('dataSourceUnproxied').getActive()
```

but it seems the functionality is removed in version grails 3 and above, is there anyway in grails 3.3.9 to get some similar functionality.

Comment: As per the docs, this bean still available. https://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/conf.html#transactionAwareDataSourceProxy

Comment: it says so but doesn't really work